# How do I have a "press enter to continue" feature in python?

Tags: python

I am writing a choose-your-own-adventure style game in python (terminal based) and I would like the program to pause printing until the `enter` button is pressed. Here is an example.

```
print("zzzzzzzzz")
```

the press enter to continue would come here. Then, after they press enter, this block would run.

```
print("yyyyyy")
```

Python 3 is preferable.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Python 2:

```
raw_input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Python 3:

```
input("Press Enter to continue...")
```

Comment: thanks, worked perfectly :)